# How to show dialog when app is in background in android app like collect app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK2Ol.png)

I am sharing a link from another app like youtube to my app but Now it opens my app and then saves the link. My need is to not save the link without opening the app

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

- You don't need dialog or anything like it. Just make the activity fully transparent, process data and finish it. Optionally, you can show Toast as a feedback. It would look and feel like everything is processed in the background.
- You need dialog or some kind of UI. For this, you can use floating windows that you can show over other apps. Many apps use this approach such as Pocket, etc. There is complete guide on how to do it: https://localazy.com/blog/floating-windows-on-android-1-jetpack-compose-room

Comment: but it open up the activity i m getting  data in menifest file

like   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: Sure, it does. There is no way around without activity, but if you make it invisible or trigger the floating window and immediately finish it, it's not interrupting at all.